# How to create Custom SOObjects using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, vs-code

I'm a .Net developer. Just started learning Salesforce. I would like to setup a dev environment using Visual Studio Code. I'm able to do that with the help of Salesforce Extension Pack.

However I'm looking for a way to create `SObjects` right from the Visual Studio Code. Is there a plugin or a command that I can use to create sfdx objects in vscode??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating Custom Objects in Salesforce via VS Code can be cumbersome, as it involves adding/manipulating metadata files that aren't so friendly to use.

I would suggest using getting familiar with the Setup -> Object Manager for full control of SObject/field creation, or use [Schema Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_modeling/schema_builder) (which is really useful for quickly creating SObjects & fields)

P.S.  There's a nice tutorial for .NET developers coming onto Salesforce on the [.NET Developers Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/microsoft_dotnet)

Comment: Thanks, Once created is there an option to export them as an .object file or something, since i would need to check in the schema to the source control

Comment: Yes, you can do it via the Salesforce CLI with commands like `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:MyCustomObject__c -u OrgWhereMyCustomObjectLives`.  Read up on [Develop Against Any Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm) for examples of force:source, and -m flag maps to [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm).  Scroll and click through the laundry list of Metadata types on the left sidebar

Comment: Sure Let me try this. Thanks for the help!!